# Why Authorization/Authentication Tokens are suggested to send only as Header

Tags: authentication, http-headers, authorization, request-headers

I would like to know why any authentication(**JWT**, etc...) tokens are suggested to send only as Header, but not as a body parameter?

1. Is there any **performance issue** while handling them from **header vs body**?
2. Is there any **security concern**?
3. Or its just a **common practice** that's just followed by the community?

Comment: Hi Karthik, just to a small addition to the good answer from Nitish. Since, headers are meta information of the request, it allows to include extra information without affecting of body structure, which makes them format-agnostic.

Answer (score 1):

The first reason is the security only. Sending tokens in the header helps protect them from being exposed in the URL or request body, reducing the risk of sensitive info being logged or cached.

The other reasons are-

1. Standardization like OAuth 2.0 and JWT making it easier for servers and clients to interpret and validate authentication info.
2. Ease of handling as they are easily accessible by servers and client-side code from headers.
3. Avoiding being stored in browsers history helps reducing security breach.
4. Cross origin Resource sharing (CORS) as certain browsers restrict the ability to include sensitive info in cross origin requests.